# How to import mgwt in UiBinder

Tags: mgwt

mgwt project website suggests using the following import statement in UiBinder:

```
xmlns:mgwt="urn:import:com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.widget"
```

It does not work, however, because every widget is in a separate package. I can make an individual widget work by changing the import statement:

```
xmlns:mgwt="urn:import:com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.widget.carousel"
```

but this is obviously inconvenient. The wildcard does not work in this import statement. Is there a better way of importing mgwt in UiBinder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package organization has changed since `mGWT` 2 and the website is not up-to-date with the last versions. However, you can still use the import suggested by the website :

```
xmlns:mgwt="urn:import:com.googlecode.mgwt.ui.client.widget"
```

But you will need to use the widgets like this :

```
<mgwt:package-name:widget-name>
    ....
</mgwt:package-name:widget-name>
```

For instance :

```
<mgwt:carousel.Carousel>
    ...
</mgwt:carousel.Carousel>
```